# Explanation of arrow and dot operator pertaining to different situations in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, object, dereference

I understand the arrow operator to mean dereference a pointer to struct/object and get member for example:

```
int test;
test = one->two;
```

`one` being the object/struct pointer and `two` being the member, in this case an integer. Essentially the same as:

```
int test;
test = (*one).two;
```

However what if `two` was a pointer to an int? How would you retrieve the integer value stored at the address pointed to by `two`?

Comment: `*( (*one).two )`  (The same way...)

Comment: Why the downvotes? I can see how this would be confusing and difficult to find an answer to. For new programmers, it is not immediately obvious how expressions are constructed from other expressions and that operators can be applied throughout.

Comment: Thanks Joseph I would like some more information about that subject. Any suggestions?

Comment: @seanr My only suggestion is to look up how expressions work in C++ (and many other languages). You probably see `*p` and understand that it means to dereference the pointer `p`, but when you see `*` in a more complex expression, it becomes harder to understand. Well in general, what you're seeing is `*<some expression>`. In the simple case, the `<some expression>` is just the name of a pointer variable (like `p`). However, that `<some expression>` can be any expression as long as it has pointer type. If `one->two` is a pointer, then you can dereference it in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*((*one).two)

or

*(one->two)
```

Comment: The outer parentheses aren't necessary.

Comment: Agreed, but they clarify what's being done, and using them saves me from having to memorize OOO.